# Why does this nested mixin repeat its parent selector?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

Why does the mixin evaluate to include the parent class (.btn-rounded), when nested inside a class rule?

bootstrap/scss/mixins:

```
@mixin media-breakpoint-down($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $max: breakpoint-max($name, $breakpoints);
  @if $max {
    @media (max-width: $max) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @content;
  }
}
```

styles.scss:

```
.btn-rounded {

    @include media-breakpoint-down(sm){
        display: none;
    }

  position: relative;
  background-color: white;

}
```

styles.css:

```
.btn-rounded {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .btn-rounded {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question, and don't tag titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries like `@media (max-width: 575.98px)` must be top level in css. So for the compiled css to work it needs to be unnested and appear on top level.

SASS automatically does that for you.

For the rules to target the proper element - even tho it has been unnested -  it needs to repeat the selector (`.btn-rounded`).

You can learn more about media queries in their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

I also found this [article](https://medium.com/@hallodom/the-solution-to-media-queries-in-sass-5493ebe16844) pretty useful on how to work around this problem in sass *in general*.

Comment: awesome thank you!